# C# HashSet Overlap Reflection

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I have two HashSets that I'm trying to use the Overlaps method with via reflection. Here's what I've got so far in LinqPad. You'll see that `invocation` works and returns `true`. I'm expecting the same to happen with `comp`.

I'm explicity trying invoke this Expression Call.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.call?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_Call_System_Reflection_MethodInfo_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_

The required parameters are `Expression.Call(MethodInfo, Expression, Expression)`

```
var bigSet = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList().ToHashSet();
var smallSet = Enumerable.Range(3, 1).ToList().ToHashSet();
var p1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(HashSet<int>));
var p2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(HashSet<int>));

MethodInfo overlap = typeof(HashSet<int>).GetMethod("Overlaps");
var body = Expression.Call(overlap, p1, p2);
var lam = Expression.Lambda<Func<HashSet<int>, HashSet<int>>>(body, p1, p2);


var invocationTest = overlap.Invoke(bigSet, new object[] { smallSet });
Console.WriteLine(invocationTest);


var comp = lam.Compile()
var x = comp(bigSet, smallSet);
```

My problem is that `comp` has an off by one error in the arguments. I think I've got `lam` written incorrectly or possibly `body` as well and thats actually causing it. Thank you

Comment: Is using expression trees a requirement?

Comment: When I try your code, I get a compiler error stating that `comp` does not take two arguments. The issue is that `Func<a,b>` is a function that takes a and returns b, so you need three type arguments to `Func`. And a semicolon after `Compile()`.

Comment: The `Expression.Call` overload you are using is for a static method with two arguments. You need the overload for a [member method with one argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.call?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_Call_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Reflection_MethodInfo_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression___).

Answer (score 1):

You have mistake in `Expression.Call` and in Lambda generic type:

```cs
var bigSet   = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList().ToHashSet();
var smallSet = Enumerable.Range(3, 1).ToList().ToHashSet();

var p1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(HashSet<int>));
var p2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(HashSet<int>));

var overlap = typeof(HashSet<int>).GetMethod("Overlaps");
var body    = Expression.Call(p1, overlap, p2);
var lam     = Expression.Lambda<Func<HashSet<int>, HashSet<int>, bool>>(body, p1, p2);

var comp = lam.Compile();
var x    = comp(bigSet, smallSet);
```